Android Studio emulator "Cant Connect Camera" using windows virtual camera from Phone Link on windows 11
I'm trying to emulate my Phone's camera to the android virtual device using Windows Phone Link connected to my S10+. The camera works fine on the windows camera app but every time I try to use it in the virtual device on Android Studio I get the error "cant connect camera".
I tried switching the front and back camera to "emulated" but that's useless to me because all it does is show me a picture of a frog or something.
In the camera options to select from I only have "webcam0" and that gives me the error I mentioned.
Sometimes it doesn't give me any error. Just gives me a gray screen with a camera icon, so I have no clue what's wrong.
I also tried OBS Virtual Camera and that doesn't work either.
I've made sure that the virtual device I'm using supports camera emulation. (x86_x64 API level 35 Android 15)
Any help would be very greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
